# What is the best way to handle folders with millions of files in RHEL-7?

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel, linux-kernel, file-copy

I am at an awkward situation. I am using the RHEL-7 machine having 62 GB RAM. In this machine, I have couple of folders where I have aound 8 million files.

Unfortunately, I am finding it hard to deal with this folders. I am finding it extremely slow to do basic operarations like listing files.

As an example, `ls -l ~/large_directory | head -5` takes a long time.

The problem worse with copy command, I have to copy files from this folder to another folder. The usual copy command `cp ~/large_directory/*.js /processing_directory/` does not work either. I presume I have to use `xargs` or something like it.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: 'ls -lrt' calls for sorting ALL the files in the directory, by modification time, newest first. So you have to access 8 million timestamps and sort them.

Comment: cp -p ... is asking to preserve the mode,ownership,timestamps - is this truly necessary?

Comment: @JeremyBoden even `cp` gives me the same problem.

Comment: How does a simple `ls -l ~/large_directory | wc -l` perform?

Comment: `ls` almost always reads the whole directory because it has a default sort order. There is an option `ls -U` *do not sort; list entries in directory order* which at least gets you the list of names fast. Also, if you just want to shift some files somewhere else, you can `ls -U | head -n 10000` to limit your arg lists, and mv a bunch of files away, and those names are nicely localised in the directory. Rinse and repeat. `find` should also read in directory order. The game is to break up the linear structure first, sort out the final catalogue later.

Comment: @JeremyBoden `ls -l ~/large_directory | wc -l` is also super slow.

Comment: @JeremyBoden Bound to be very slow. It needs to read the whole directory first, because it will sort in alphabetic order and can't know which is first until it has them all. It will also (on most fs) need also to read every inode to get the timestamp, permissions etc. Only then can it output the first line. `ls -U` starts output immediately -- you can at least see some of what you are dealing with easily. Do you need the files -- are they ever going to be useful?

Comment: I have around 80 lines of tested bash+awk that will move files from a huge directory into many small ones. It runs 100,000 files in 96 seconds on a Laptop and HDD. I will time it on a million files later, but I see no reason for it not to be linear time. My current rule is to base the target directory on a short random section of the filename, but doing it by e.g. file extension would be simple.

Comment: I have a script that will split one million files and move them into 1000 new directories in 30 minutes (on a Laptop with an old HDD). It needs extra rules on what goes where. Ask a new question with more specifics if you want to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Read `man find xargs cp`, and do something like

```
find ~/bigdir -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r echo cp --target-directory=~/destination
```

Remove the "`echo`" when you're happy with the results.

Comment: Even better, why not use `-exec command + {}` option provided by `find`? It works the same way as `xargs`, but save you a process to create and the IPC overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Midnight Commander is a tool that can help you to work with a little more comfort, in this case. It lists files using stream, like less, so in theory it will, as possible, have a good performance.

It also provides the "Filter" functionality, so it can be used before copying any file. It will make it easier to visualize your files, so it won't be necessary to list files over and over again. Plus, with the View/Edit functionality, you'll be able to open a file and edit a file without have to list the folder again.

Answer (score 0):

just kinda throwing this out there...

what's wrong with a shell script to do something like

```
tar -cf newdir/a/a.tar /hugedir/a*
tar -cf newdir/b/b.tar hugedir/b*
```

or, a similar type thing,

```
cd hugedir/
mkdir a
mkdir b
ln -s a* ./a/
ln -s b* ./b/
```

Yet another idea might be to use a language, python or bash, that can go through a logic list/loop or comparison logic (whatever the language happens to support and makes since) that will act upon each file in disk order as opposed to a sorted order.  Yes, a scripted method will access each and every file, and it'll take forever, but it will only do it one time.

with that high of a file count, there has to be a very simple way of sorting it into smaller chunks to work with.

Personally, I'm curious what these files are, and I'm sure lots of other people would like to know also.

Comment: I had a contract on a site where some fool had tested cron as root during installation, and omitted to remove it. Eight years on, I had 160 servers all failing at the same time, root partition full, each server with 4 million+ unread emails addressed to root.

Comment: The issue with both the tar and the ln is the shell's filename expansion of a* etc. [A] each expansion will read the whole directory anyway. [B] The shell explicitly sorts the matching files just like ls would. [C] The resulting arg lists passed to tar and ln would break the command-line limit. Any effective way to fix this issue has to process the files in raw directory order.

Answer (score 0):

`cpio` in pass-through mode is quite efficient and was popular at one time for very large directory trees with huge numbers of files.

```
$ find /bigdatadir -print | cpio -pdm /newbigdatadir
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about this problem from the end aim, not the current situation.

That is: what is the final result you are trying to achieve? I would suggest you might have aims like:

.. Restructure all the files into a new directory with suitable multi-level tree structure.

.. Remove (eventually) the files from the original directory so you can `rmdir` it when empty, and recover the space occupied by the directory itself.

A directory cannot contain duplicate names, so you have 8 million unique names. That suggests a filename structure based on date, time, serial number, project code etc. It would be helpful to understand what that structure is, because it will suggest the partitioning of the final result (e.g. like `./2018/20180923/syslogs/...` if they are date-stamped logs).

Solutions involving `cp`, `tar`, `ln` are not helpful because they leave the original directory unchanged. Specifically, `cp` will duplicate the whole data set, taking huge space and time. You really need to `mv` the files to their new location.

You can't even `rmdir hugedir` at the end, because it will not remove a directory with files in. `rm -rf hugedir` is no help: it merely recurses by running `rm -r *` on the directory tree anyway, so it still runs like a dog.

This will only work well if you (a) process files in batches; (b) select batches of files in raw directory order; (c) delete files as you go. Deleting files in raw order does not make those directory blocks go away (might do on ext4 but don't rely on it), but they are much faster to scan past again if they are empty (and quite possibly cached).

Having been here myself, the solution I found was:

(1) Establish the new structure and create all required directories.

(2) `ls -U hugedir | head -n 10000` to efficiently get a file list of manageable size, working from the head of the directory.

(3) Pass that list to a script that moves each file to its new location, using the rules you decided previously. If you can group those `mv` commands by target directory (`mv -t aa bb cc ...`) that would optimise slightly. `mv` will also delete them from `hugedir` as efficiently as possible.

(4) Rinse and repeat until `hugedir` contains no files (`ls -U` returns no names). In this case, repeat around 800 times (in a script loop, obviously).

(5) If this data is precious, it is worth setting up a cut-down test directory to prove suitability and timings. In particular, I would make a full `ls -U > myTestList.txt`, and run that through my names rules incrementally, counting by target, and have a catch-all for any unexpected name formats.

Of course, if you just want to dismantle hugedir without rationalising the data structure, you could just split the files into 3000 directories of 3000 files, or a 200/200/200 tree split. But you would still be hunting for specific files all the time.

If you can post a few sample names by editing your question, or a larger list in PasteBin, I can show some script.

I made two million empty files in one directory (taking 13 minutes). My timings show `ls` is almost 10 times slower than `ls -U`, and `ls -l` is almost 20 times slower. I would expect eight million to be proportionately worse. `ls -U | head -n 10000` returns the first group of names in 0.034 secs.

```
$ time ls -U HugeDir | wc -l  #.. takes real    0m3.962s
$ time ls HugeDir    | wc -l  #.. takes real    0m38.135s
$ time ls -l HugeDir | wc -l  #.. takes real    1m14.688s
```

`find` also reads the raw directory order, and handles unusual filenames (e.g. spaces, newlines and special characters) better than `ls`.

```
$ time find HugeDir -type f -print | wc -l  #.. takes real  0m8.566s
```